# Pandas: Some part of index as repeating column values

Tags: pandas

Following dataframe with 'date' & 'total' repeating but attributes-names are unique every time.

```
l0       l1                              Value
001  attribute1                           1
     attribute2                           5
     attribute3                           8
     date                                 1/1/20
     total                                500
002  somethingelse(notAttribute-1)        84
     somethingelse-entirely               24  
     date                                 2/2/20 
     total                                1000 
.
.
.
040
```

Need guidance to make it as follows, as this requires extracting a specific part of index (last 2  values of level 1 (l1) per level 0 (l0).)

```
l0      l1                             Value     date     total
001  attribute1                           1       1/1/20    500
     attribute2                           5       1/1/20    500
     attribute3                           8       1/1/20    500   
002  somethingelse(notAttribute-1)        84      2/2/20    1000
     somethingelse-entirely               24      2/2/20    1000
.
.
.
040
```

Comment: is `l0` index?=

Comment: your data looks like a multi-index. If i am right, could you share the dict form? that would be easier to read in and work on. just a couple of df.head().to_dict()

Comment: Yes. l0 and l1 are indexes. This is multi-index. This has been extracted from a json file with has nested dictionaries in it.

Comment: please tell me if my solution works

Comment: I am so sorry. I have messed up by over-simplifying the problem. While I am sure your solution works for my example, the real nested dictionaries are from a json file. In them, there are multiple 'Value' columns (think of value1, value2, value3..) but the 'date' and 'total' is the same in each column since they are related to the index labels 1, 2 and so on and not in any way to value columns. I think it would be more correct to put data and total in a multi-index form as another level of indexing. Again, apologies for the mess up.

Comment: then you should show an example of this json in other question and consider accept this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df.set_index(['l0','l1'])
print(df)
                                    Value
l0 l1                                    
1  attribute1                           1
   attribute2                           5
   attribute3                           8
   date                            1/1/20
   total                              500
2  somethingelse(not-attribute-1)      84
   somethingelse-entirely              24
   date                            2/2/20
   total                             1000
```

---

**Solution**: [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) + [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
new_df = (df['Value'].unstack('l1')
                     .reset_index()
                     .melt(['l0','date','total'])
                     .dropna()
                     .set_index(['l0','l1']))
print(new_df)
                                     date total value
l0 l1                                                
1  attribute1                      1/1/20   500     1
   attribute2                      1/1/20   500     5
   attribute3                      1/1/20   500     8
2  somethingelse(not-attribute-1)  2/2/20  1000    84
   somethingelse-entirely          2/2/20  1000    24
```